# Load image from any source into a MAUI WIndows app

Tags: c#, maui

I am currently writing a program that should load images from a FTP directory after a TCP/IP event. The images are copied before the arrival of the message from a camera into this FTP directory. The names of these images should appear in a list and when you click on them, the image should appear open in a view.
Until now I only knew that an image was already in the Resources/Image folder. But in my case this has to be done dynamically.

I have already tried to load an image with an absolute path but this does not seem to work.

```
<Image
    Source="Y:/Images/dotnet_bot.png"
    SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
    HeightRequest="200"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

For helpful tips and suggestions I would be very grateful

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Comment: @Jason Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. It must always be possible for the user to choose the directory in which the program searches for images. For example F:\Images

Comment: this is addressed in that doc: "In addition to the default locations, an app can access additional files and folders by declaring capabilities in the app manifest or by calling a file picker to let the user pick files and folders for the app to access."

Comment: The user is not allowed to select files, but an engine number is sent from an interface and then all images that contain this engine number in their name are displayed in a list. The user then simply clicks on the image he wants to have displayed.

Comment: you just said "It must always be possible for the user to choose the directory"

Comment: Ok, right. It was expressed a little unfortunate. In the settings you must be able to set where images are stored. In this place the program has to search for new images when a new engine number is set. But you don't open a directory like in an open dialog.

Comment: then put a folder picker in the settings page, and see the section "Retaining access to files and folders"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254898/discussion-between-daver-and-jason).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use the `ImageSources` instead of using the `Image`. The property `FromFile` can return a `FileImageSource` that reads an image from a local file.

Besides, `ImageSources` also has other properties to choose. You can check this [.NET MAUI Community Toolkit ImageSources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/imagesources/) for more information.